# how to detect when the user drop an image inside browser current tab viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

i want to know how to do the drag and drop image upload.the thing i don't understand is that how to let server know when a user drops an image inside a certain div or to body for uploading?is that supported in all common browsers ie,ff,chrome,safari. thank you :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Server won't know that you've dropped something in your browser's window.It's javascript,html5 which will detect that you've dropped something in your browser window and inform the server using ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can tell you haven't done much research.

Short answer is, no. There is no method that is supported in *all* major browsers that will detect when a user drops an image inside the client window.

Also, as Rajat Saxena pointed out in the comments, you'd have to inform the server of a file drop by sending an ajax request on the drop event.

---

### HTML5

Here's [drag and drop from desktop to browser](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd) using HTML5 and javascript

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

---

### JQuery

Here's a [drag and drop from desktop to browser](http://jxs.me/2010/09/20/drag-and-drop-with-jquery/) using JQuery (Firefox and Chrome)

```
function ignoreDrag(e) {
  e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
  e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
}

$('#target')
    .bind('dragenter', ignoreDrag)
    .bind('dragover', ignoreDrag);
    .bind('drop', drop);

function drop(e) {
  ignoreDrag(e);
  var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  if(dt.files.length > 0){
    var file = dt.files[0];
    alert(file.name);
  }
}
```

---

### Other related links to plugins (not tested) and questions

- [Is there a good jQuery Drag-and-drop file upload plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin)
- [file upload via drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739085/file-upload-via-drag-and-drop)
- [jQuery Drag Image From Desktop Plugin](http://strd6.com/2011/01/jquery-drag-image-from-desktop-plugin/)
- [Drag-n-Drop from Desktop jQuery Plugin](http://xquerywebappdev.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/drag-n-drop-from-desktop-jquery-plugin/)
- [Javascript for Drag file From desktop and drop into webpage](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/578735-javascript-drag-file-desktop-drop-into-webpage)
- [jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Pupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for it.
I don't have to worry about how to implement this drag and drop behavior and it gracefully degrades if the browser isn't html 5 compatible.